# Silverlight Event Log in Isolated Storage

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, event-log, isolatedstorage

Has anyone written an event log that uses Isolated Storage in Silverlight 3?
Any suggestions on implementing one?

Specific questions:

1. Should I keep a stream writer open, or should I open,write, and close for each entry?
2. How should I remove items from the log atomically?

Comment: Other criteria needed, how robust does this need to be, i.e. how often to you need to flush?  What Thread safety considerations are there, could multiple threads be trying to add a log at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I heard [clog](http://www.codeplex.com/Clog) from codeplex is pretty good although it targets wcf, i read on codeproject about about a [log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightLogging.aspx?df=100&forumid=907929&exp=0) approach that works for silverlight, although both of these log 2 wcf services, im sure with a bit of tweaking you can modify this to write to isolated storage

Answer (score 0):

[Crypto Logger](http://www.ssware.com/cryptologger/logger-net.htm) supports Silverlight apps and libraries and it can log to its UI console via TCP, to isolated storage and also to the Browser Console (like Firebug in FireFox) or the in-built one in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN article on [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.95).aspx) and [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile(v=vs.95).aspx)

> **Thread Safety**
>
> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any
> instance members are not guaranteed to
> be thread safe.